# How do I insert 3 separate rounded images above 3 separate columns?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: #911f3c
}

.content-title {
  font-family: teko;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  font-family: teko;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.column-left {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 30%;
}

.column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
}

.column-center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="content-title">
  Explore - Discover - Enjoy
</h3>


<div class="container">
  <div class="column-center">Explore the limitless archive of the worlds highest quality cinematic sports videos </div>
  <div class="column-left">Enjoy the vast selection of videos and learn the stories behind the creation of the art</div>
  <div class="column-right">Discover your favourite film makers, content creators and athletes within the industry</div>
</div>
```

I am creating a quick project for uni and i am struggling on this one little aspect. I really want to add 3 separate, relatively small, rounded images  below the 3 word title but above each column (see the attached image). But every time I do it all the text moves around and it just being a massive pain.

How can I get this working?

[image]

Comment: im not looking to replace the text with images. i would like to add an image just above each piece of text

Comment: Put the image tags just before your text and set the images to be `display: block;` - By default, images are `display: inline;` and will try to fit beside the text, however `display: block;` will force anything after the image to be moved to the next line. It seems like this is what you're after. `<img style="display: block;" src="my/image.png" />` **or** do it in css: `.container img { display: block; }`

Comment: I added the background color so one could see the text when running the snippet. Please do run the snippet before posting to ensure it demonstrates the problem. You don't have an `<img>` elements in your snippet, which makes it hard to understand what you're trying to do. Try linking to images from, say, https://dummyimage.com/ or http://lorempixel.com/ with the size you want the images.

Comment: I have changed the attached image to show what i am trying to do. seemed to be the easiest way to show you guys.

Comment: Use `display:block;` on the images or a container for those images. The `img` tag is an inline element by default, so it will want to be inline with text.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not using any framework like bootstrap, this should do the trick:

```css
body {
  background: #911f3c
}

.content-title {
  font-family: teko;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.col-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.col-content {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-content img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.col-content p {
  font-family: teko;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="content-title">
  Explore - Discover - Enjoy
</h3>

<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-content">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/">
      <p>
        Explore the limitless archive of the worlds highest quality cinematic sports videos
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-content">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/">
      <p>
        Discover your favourite film makers, content creators and athletes within the industry
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-content">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/">
      <p>
        Enjoy the vast selection of videos and learn the stories behind the creation of the art
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: why with Firefox 51.0.1 I can't see the three images with a circular shape? Have you considered to add a CSS rule like the following `border-radius: 50%;`?

Comment: @sentenza you're right, but I think the OP was just looking for a way to properly position images ;)

Comment: *I really want to add 3 separate, relatively small, **rounded** images*

I understood he needs them to be rounded also... :/